# How does a winform event hook up the win32 messages

Tags: winforms

any article talk about how a winform event hook up the win32 message?

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc%28VS.71%29.aspx) what you are looking for?